# Div does not fill parent with width:100%

Tags: html, css

**html**

```
<main>
    <div class="homediv">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</main
```

**CSS**

```
div.homediv {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  /*The lower the z-index, the further in the background the element*/
  z-index: -1;
}
```

At first glance, this should make the div horizontally fill the screen. But it did not. A few answers on here said that the width:100% will only work when the width of the parent is set, but that was set. To ensure that, I even gave html, body, main and my div the width:100% attribute.
This did not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying around in the chrome DevTools, I found out that main does fill the screen width. But it contained some seemingly pre-set attributes that I had to remove. Google told me that padding and margin are - if not specified - set by the browser, so to fix the css, I had to add

```
main {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think space is from `<body>` tag, not `<main>` so try

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But if you use a reset CSS you don't have this problems. Read about importance of CSS reset. You can use [this](https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) but also it's a lot good resets.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code, I hope it works for you:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```